# problem with acer dvd writer(don't accept dvd-r disks)

Tags: laptop, dvd

dvd writer of my acer laptop don't burn disk with burn programs
the write programs warn me that your dvd must be dvd+r but my dvds is dvd-r
but windows disk image burner can be write the image files to disks.

i'll be hope if someone can help me
with regards

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

@ultrasawblade
if my dvd writer don't support dvd-r for writing then the windows disk image burner too can't write dvd-r disks.
but my  windows disk image burner can write image files onto any disks.
i want to support burn programs to write to disks also.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

DVD "plus" R and DVD "minus" R are different.  I would think by now that all writers are pretty much "multiformat", meaning they'll read/write both, but your laptop may have a lower-cost burner that only works with the DVD "plus" R's.

Comment: i said that this writer can write image files with "windows image burner" on win7-so my writer can write dvd-r disks but not with burn programs